# Montar query para consulta em banco de acordo com checks marcados

Tags: php, html, mysql

Tenho a seguinte situação, o usuário pode selecionar o nível do idioma, como:
Básico, Intermediário ou Avançado e disponho a ele em forma de checkbox.

Preciso montar uma query dinâmica de acordo com a ou as opções selecionadas pelo usuário, como exemplo, se o mesmo escolher as opções de nível Básico e Intermediário, como poderia montar essa query para efetuar a pesquisa? Podendo ser uma, duas ou todas as opções.

Um exemplo dessa como estava fazendo essa pesquisa, de forma errônea:

```
if ($NivelIngles != ""){        
    if ( $lcWhere <> "" ) {
        $lcWhere.= " AND (`candidato`.NivelIngles = '$NivelIngles ')";
    } else {
        $lcWhere.= " WHERE (`candidato`.NivelIngles = '$NivelIngles ')";
    }       
}
```

O resultado antes de montar minha pesquisa está assim:

```
Array ( [0] => Basico [1] => Intermediario )
```

Espero que tenha conseguido explicar minha questão

Answer (score 4, accepted):

### Caso a grafia do DB seja a mesma do form:

```
$checkboxes = Array( 'Básico', 'Avançado' );

$query = 'SELECT * FROM cursos';
$cola = ' WHERE '; // Deixar os espaços em branco "em volta".

foreach ($checkboxes as $nivel) {
   //$nivel = mysqli_real_escape_string( $nivel ) pra prevenir injection. Adapte ao caso.
   $query .= $cola.' `candidato`.`NivelIngles` = "'.$nivel.'" ';
   $cola = ' OR ';
}

echo $query;
```

### Caso use grafia diferente dos ítens:

Segue uma opção sem loop, caso a escrita no DB esteja diferente do `form`
(`Básico` x `Basico`, por exemplo) :

```
$checkboxes = Array( 'Básico', 'Avançado' );

$query = 'SELECT * FROM cursos';
$cola = ' WHERE '; // Deixar os espaços em branco "em volta".

if ( in_array( 'Básico', $checkboxes ) ) {  // Escrever igual ao Form
   $query .= $cola.' `candidato`.`NivelIngles` = "Basico" '; // Escrever igual ao DB
   $cola = ' OR ';
}
if ( in_array( 'Intermediário', $checkboxes ) ) {  // Escrever igual ao Form
   $query .= $cola.' `candidato`.`NivelIngles` = "Intermediario" '; // Escrever igual ao DB
   $cola = ' OR ';
}
if ( in_array( 'Avançado', $checkboxes ) ) {  // Escrever igual ao Form
   $query .= $cola.' `candidato`.`NivelIngles` = "Avancado" '; // Escrever igual ao DB
   $cola = ' OR ';
}

echo $query;
```

Resultado:

```
SELECT * FROM cursos
    WHERE `candidato`.`NivelIngles` = "Basico"  OR  `candidato`.`NivelIngles` = "Avancado"
```

<sub>Quebra de linha adicionada para legibilidade</sub>

> Lembre-se de digitar a cedilha e os acentos da mesma forma que está no `form` nos `if`s e na query, senão as comparações falharão.

PS: As soluções aqui apresentadas servem para localizar mostrando todos os resultados, caso nenhum checkbox esteja selecionado.

Comment: Olá Bacco, muito obrigado pela excelente ajuda, mas estou com uma dificuldade para adaptar essa query ao modelo que tenho aqui, pois vou concatenando opções com WHERE e AND para depois gerar a consulta, será que pode me dar mais essa dica? O modelo passei na postagem inicial.

Comment: Basta adicionar as condições adicionais assim, após o código mencionado: `$query .= $cola.' curso="alemao" '; $cola = ' AND '` e repetir para todas as cláusulas adicionais. O segredo está na `$cola` que vai ser 'WHERE' ou 'AND' automaticamente.

Comment: Seria interessante um exemplo mais concreto de query, para que eu possa ver o que você precisa, pois quando se usa OR e and, é importante que estejam agrupados corretamente com `( )` pra dar o efeito desejado.

Comment: Como posso te passar? Pelo comentário o espaço é pequeno e a questão do AND e OR é o que mais pesa.

Comment: Aí já não sei se seria um caso de uma nova questão, ou editar e acrescentar embaixo da existente. Mas teria que ter um certo cuidado, pois se alterar demais a essência da pergunta original, prejudica as respostas já existentes... Se achar que é o caso de nova pergunta, seria bom ser bem específico para explicar os requisitos e o problema com detalhes, assim não corre o risco de determinada resposta não te atender 100%.

Answer (score 2):

Uma opção também seria você fazer `WHERE column IN`, exemplo:

```
$checkboxes = array('Basico','Intermediario');

$whereClause = "'".implode("','", $checkboxes)."'";
$query = "SELECT * FROM cursos WHERE `candidato`.`NivelIngles` IN ($whereClause);";
```

**Obs**: Sua query está selecionando na tabela *cursos* e seu `WHERE` filtrando na tabela *candidato*, suponho que você esteja fazendo um `JOIN` das duas tabelas.

[**Exemplo SQLFiddle**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/e0b4e/1)

Comment: Olá abfurlan, sim estou fazendo um JOIN.