# como fazer uma query que o próprio usuário pode gerar?

Tags: php, mysql

Existe algum material para se aprender?

Por exemplo:

Eu tenho um pet shop:

Digamos que no meu HTML eu tenho vários select boxes (animal, raça, sexo, idade, etc), nele eu posso

- selecionar o cachorro ou
- selecionar cachorro > raça ou
- selecionar cachorro > raça > sexo ou
- selecionar cachorro > raça > idade ou
- selecionar cachorro > idade > sexo ou
- etc

  e vice versa para múltiplas opções.

Como é feito uma *query* pra cada uma delas, sendo que as opções de escolhas vão variar bastante?

`select * from nomeTabela WHERE animal='cachorro' AND raca='pintcher'` <- Tem como fazer essa parte dinâmica? É só adicionar os `AND` e o valor dinamicamente, não é? Como eu faço isso? Eu tenho que produzir manualmente toda a *query* pra cada um dos casos? É muito trabalhoso, não é?

Comment: Tente usar o WHERE tampo = '' OR campo2 = '' OR campo3 = ''...

Comment: Talvez [essa pergunta](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/17550/91) ajude

Comment: A resposta desta também, pode te dar uma idéia de como elaborar... usando o if(empty()): http://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/71394/model-fechamento-customizar-c%C3%B3digo

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Uma vez resolvi esse problema num sistema de busca que tinha muitos campos opcionais.

Mais ou menos assim:

```
$wheres = "";//cria uma string vazia pra receber a clausula where no SQL
$first = true;//variavel pra controlar que é o primeiro campo opcional

//esse $array_busca era simplesmente o $_POST do arquivo.
foreach ($array_busca as $busca) {

    $valor = $busca['valor'];
    $campo_busca = $busca['nome_campo'];

    $where = $campo_busca." = '".$valor."'";
    /*
    Pro caso de haver um campo DATA que precisa ser tratado de um jeito especial. Inclui um tratamento para as datas que estiverem com '/'ao invés de '-'.
       if ($campo_busca == "DATA") {
        $valor = explode(';',$valor);
        $data_ini = implode('-',array_reverse(explode('/',$valor[0]))) ;
        $data_fin = implode('-',array_reverse(explode('/',$valor[1])));

        $where = "(DATA BETWEEN '".$data_ini."' AND '".$data_fin."')";

    }   */  
        if ($first == true) {
                $wheres = $where;
                $first = false;
        } else {
                $wheres = $wheres." AND ".$where;
             }  
        }
if ($wheres != "") {
  $wheres = "WHERE ".$wheres;
} else {
  $wheres = ""; 
}
$query = "SELECT * FROM TABELA ".$wheres." ORDER BY DATA";
```

Pode não ser o mais eficiente, mas resolveu :P